# How to print table rows with table rows children in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am looking for a way to print data received from API in a table working with Angular. The table have different collapses. The collapses have several rows which at the same time these rows have children rows and some of them have more children rows.

this is the json file:

```
{
  "collapse1": [
    {
      "name": "Soil",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Shopping",
          "budget": 12345
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial",
          "budget": 12345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Exterior",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Shopping",
          "budget": 12345
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial",
          "budget": 12345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Obra",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Shopping",
          "budget": 12345
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial",
          "budget": 12345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Professional honoraries",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Shopping",
          "budget": 12345
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial",
          "budget": 12345
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "collapse2":[
    {
      "name": "Soil",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Shopping",
          "budget": 12345
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial",
          "budget": 12345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Construction",
      "budget": 12345,
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "Data Center",
          "budget": 12345,
          "child": [
            {
              "name": "Development & Design",
              "budget": 12345,
              "child": [
                {
                  "name": "Raw Land",
                  "budget": 12345
                },
                {
                  "name": "Land Development",
                  "budget": 12345
                },
                {
                  "name": "Fiber Connection Upgrade",
                  "budget": 12345
                }
            
              ]
            }
        
          ]
      }
     
  ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically print a table with data like in the json file. I tried to do the following just for the first collapse, but it did not work.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let collapse of collapse1">
            <tr class="group2 collapse" [collapse]="isCollapsedGroup2">
              <td>{{ collapse.name }}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let child of collapse1.child">
              <tr class="tablerow-sub collapse" [collapse]="isCollapsedGroup2">
                <td>
                  <em class="pl-3">{{ child.name }}</em>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-template to have a recursive loop in the template like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-excmau?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
<ng-template #row let-data="collapse">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.budget }}</td>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.child">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of data.child" [ngTemplateOutlet]="row"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ collapse: child }"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let c of collapse">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="row" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ collapse: c }"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```